# Sendto- forcing sending a UDP datagram of X bytes

Tags: sockets, udp

I have a basic question on sendto:

Suppose we wish that the destination will receive a UDP packet of exactly X bytes. That means, it cannot receive a packet of less than X bytes (which is possible if sendto returns less than X bytes). Is it possible to force the sender to send exactly X bytes, or even to return an error if it is not possible? (i.e., the receiver either will get the packet of X bytes, or will not get the packet).

Edit:
If the number of bytes sent is always X, then  why the return value (the number of bytes sent) might be less than the number of bytes of the sent data (as explained in 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-sendto
) and be non-negative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That means, it cannot receive a packet of less than X bytes (which is possible if sendto returns less than X bytes).

This will never happen on a UDP socket. From [the `send(2)` manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/send):

> If the message is too long to pass atomically through the underlying protocol, the error `EMSGSIZE` is returned, and the message is not transmitted.

In short, the behavior you are asking for is already present by default.

Comment: And UDP would be unusable were this not the case. Considering that datagrams can be dropped, duplicated, or re-ordered, it would be almost impossible to use UDP if the implementation could split data in this way.

Comment: But the number of bytes that are actual sent can be less than the number of bytes of the sent buffer. As in 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-sendto

Comment: @user3563894 Not in the context of a UDP socket. Remember that `sendto()` can be used on any socket; it can return a partial write for other types of sockets.

Comment: Thanks :) this is exactly what I needed to hear